# Add Blogger blog title inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I designed a few Blogger templates and I want to add the credit with the client blog's title. The tag that would display the Blogger blog's title is this `<data:blog.title/>` but doesn't work inside this function:

*function credit(){ var creditsyear = new Date(), fullYear = creditsyear.getFullYear(), html=""+fullYear+" © . Credit", containers=document.getElementsByClassName("content"), container=document.body; if(containers.length > 0) container=containers[containers.length-1]; container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",html); }; $(document).ready(credit);*

How can I make it display the title like this:
`2016 © Blog Title. Designed by Blogger`?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Maybe u forgot to load the jQuery

```js
function credit(){ 
  var creditsyear = new Date(), fullYear = creditsyear.getFullYear(), html=""+fullYear+" © . Credit", containers=document.getElementsByClassName("content"), container=document.body; 

if(containers.length > 0) 
  container=containers[containers.length-1];

container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",html); 
}; 
$(document).ready(credit);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div>test1</div>
      <div>test2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My question was how to display the Blogger's title inside this function.

Comment: $('#content').append(BlogguerData.feed.entry[0].title.$t);